# C: reducing runtime for optimization

Tags: c, optimization, time, profiling, gprof

I have below output from `gprof` for my program:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
  0.00      0.00     0.00    30002     0.00     0.00  insert
  0.00      0.00     0.00    10124     0.00     0.00  getNode
  0.00      0.00     0.00     3000     0.00     0.00  search
  0.00      0.00     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  initialize
```

I have done optimizations and the run time I have is 0.01 secs(this is being calculated on a server where I'm uploading my code) which is the least I am getting at the moment. I am not able to reduce it further, though I want to. Does the 0.01 sec run time of my program has anything to do with the sampling time I see above in `gprof` output.
Call graph is as below:

```
gprof -q ./a.out gmon.out 
             Call graph (explanation follows)


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) no time propagated

index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00   30002/30002       main [10]
[1]      0.0    0.00    0.00   30002         insert [1]
                0.00    0.00   10124/10124       getNode [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00   10124/10124       insert [1]
[2]      0.0    0.00    0.00   10124         getNode [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00    3000/3000        main [10]
[3]      0.0    0.00    0.00    3000         search [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [10]
[4]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         initialize [4]
-----------------------------------------------
 While using `time /bin/sh -c ' ./a.out < inp.in '` on my machine I get below which varies slightly on every run .
real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.016s
sys         0m0.004s

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I am bit confused how to correlate `time` output and `gprof` o/p

Comment: Do you want help optimizing your code? It can't be done if we don't know your code and what it does. Or do you have a question about understanding `gprof` output? If so, it isn't clear what's the question.

Comment: `gprof` measures time by counting samples. Samples happen every 10 msec. So you're on the edge between getting 0 and 1 samples.

Comment: To get a better measurement, run the code many times from inside `main()`.  Aim for something like 5 seconds: enough to get good sampling without taking all day.

Answer (score 0):

According to your other question, you got it from 8 seconds down to 0.01 seconds.
That's pretty good.

Now if you want to go further, first do as @Peter suggested in his comment.
Run the code many times inside `main()` so it runs long enough to get samples.

Then you could try [*my favorite technique*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).
It will be much more informative than `gprof`.

P.S. Don't worry about CPU percent.
All it tells is if your machine is busy and not doing much I/O.
It does not tell you anything about your program.

Comment: I have managed to reduce runtime further with one big optimization. I was calling an insert into trie function with parameters as trie's root and a string. I was then using strlen to calculate length of string (this insert was getting called some 30k times). I was building this string in main. Now I just added one more parameter to insert func for string length, and passed the variable to it which was being used to build string. Lot of saving :) strlen overhead removed